# Alternative to _path

Tags: ruby, padrino, pdfkit

I am following a tutorial from railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit) and have become stuck when trying to implement the link for a PDF. The original code was:

```
<p id="pdf_link"><%= link_to "Download Invoice (PDF)", order_path(@order, :format => "pdf") %></p>
```

I am however using haml so I have edited the line as follows:

```
= link_to 'Download PDF', order_path(@order, :format => "pdf")
```

I have realised that order_path would relate to a route specified in routes.rb. The problem is my application does not have a route folder (inherited the application from another developer). Therefore how would i go about creating this path in haml code.

Also I was wondering about replacing @order. In looking through the code i noticed it is declared as such. Could someone explain what this piece of code declares order as?

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Is this a Rails question or a Sinatra question? Sinatra doesn’t have `link_to` and `_path` methods by itself.

Comment: @matt I'm not quite sure. This application is strange it has references to Sinatra but link_to etc works in it so you tell me is it Rails or Sinatra or can it be both?

Comment: Is it [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) perhaps?

Comment: I think it may well be. It really confuses me that there are references to all three within the code so I'm never 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Routes, in Rails, are declared in the `config/routes.rb` file. Take a look ate [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info.

The `order_path` is a helper method that rails provide to you when you declare your routes. You can see these routes aliases by runnig the `rake routes` command in your application root folder.

Regarding to this line:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
```

This will try to get an `Order` from the database using the passed id in the request parameters. See [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) for more information.

My advise, read the entire [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) so you know what are you dealing with.